# CSS differences between Firefox and Chrome - vertical height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having some trouble getting Firefox and Chrome to display a small section of CSS properly.

I've broken it down as much as possible and created a Codepen to illustrate the problem.

When viewed in Firefox, everything displays as intended (vertically centered). With Chrome, the labels are slightly too high, by one or two pixels.

Everything I've tried so far (adjusting padding, changing floats, adding inline-block, adding margins) will always display incorrectly in one of the two browsers.

What I'd like to know then is what the root cause of the issue is. I use a CSS reset (normalise.css) which is added to the Pen.

Link: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Vintage/pen/epEGyp)

```
<div class="editbox">
    <div class="object objecthover edit">
        <label class="t">Edit</label>
    </div>
    <div class="object objecthover lock">
        <label class="text_label">Lock</label>
        <label class="gems index-gems">50 </label>
    </div>
</div>

.editbox {
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 192px;
    background-color: #516580;
    padding-top: 12px;
    left: 0px;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.edit, .save {
    min-width: 50px;
    padding: 7px;
}
.editbox label {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 35px;
}
.editbox .object {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.lock {
    width: 130px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 5px 1px 5px 0px;
}
.lock .text_label {
    display: inline-block;
}
.editbox label {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 35px;
}
.lock label.index-gems {
    padding: 0px;
}
label.index-gems {
    color: #FFF;
    height: 27px;
    padding: 4px;
}
.editbox .lock::after, .editbox .make_bid::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your CSS please?

Comment: you should also include your CSS in the question. The CSS on the codepen is malformed by the way. I don't at a glance see anything in the CSS that's attempting to vertically centre the text. I suspect the fact it's centred for you on Firefox is really just luck. On my Firefox on Mac, it looks the same as in Chrome - may be down to differences in fonts. There are a number of techniques for vertically centring - for example if you set the `height` and `line-height` of a container to the same value it will be vertically centred, but you'll need to re-jig things a bit to get that to work for you

Comment: CSS added. As the .object divs are at a set height, I've used padding to attempt to vertically align.

The text for me is in the correct place when I view that pen on Firefox but not on Chrome.

I'll play around with line-height

Comment: Here's a start: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNJWbo

Comment: Your pen differs in appearance for me with Chrome and Firefox (as mine does). Does it look the same on both browsers for you?

Comment: They look the same here in the different browsers. As @CupawnTae says, are you sure you're the same default font and size on yours? Since the Codepen doesn't specify font-family and font-size, both browsers take those from their user's preferences.

Comment: note that setting `vertical-align: middle` is not enough for vertically centring text - that only works in table cells (or other elements explicitly set to `display: table-cell`). And trying to use padding to vertically align text is a sure path to madness.

Comment: @isherwood thank you, line height solved the issue. Mr Lister I checked and both browsers have the same default font and font size, really odd I'm seeing different and on two different machines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to vertically align text using padding is unreliable. Two better ways are

1. use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`
2. set the `line-height` of your element to the same as the `height`.

The first option handles multi-line text where the second doesn't, but introducing table cells can lead to other layout issues. If you're only ever dealing with a single line of text, the second option is more straightforward.

Here's an example of using `line-height` to vertically align text:

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #abc;
}
.a {
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.b {
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.c {
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.d {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.e {
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">text</div>
<div class="b">text</div>
<div class="c">text</div>
<div class="d">text</div>
<div class="e">text</div>
```